Does flyway validate table schema against entity in spring boot?
I am trying to create a service which should use existing database (Producton) which is already using flyway. I want to add flyway migrations to my service and those migration should not delete existing schema and create new empty schema.
I am using CREATE IF NOT EXISTS to make sure that my script should not delete existing table and create same table again without any data.
Before I proceed with it, I just want to know does flyway validate table schema against entity and second question is what will be better choice to start with flyway migration with existing database which is also using flyway migration.
I have tried using IF NOT EXISTS in scripts to avoid deletion of existing table in database.
I am expecting answers for two queries -
1 - does flyway validate table schema against entity
2 - Better solution for flyway migration when we are dealing with existing database (which is using flyway)

Solution 1: Simple: Ignore your idea about validate entities by Flyway, use JPA. In your application.properties add
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate

Reference document: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization.using-hibernate
Solution 2:
./flyway -validateOnMigrate="true" migrate

Reference documents:

https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/validate-on-migrate-224919759.html
https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/validate-184127464.html


Thank you for your response. I am more concern about migration here. As I mentioned in my query that I am developing a service which suppose to use existing database (Production) which is already using flyway. so in this case if I use flyway migration in my service will that clean everything from production database? and for more knowledge point of view, I want to understand does flyway validate schema table against entity? if you can clear my understanding here that will be more helpful.

Don't touch production database. 1) Back up production database at not rush hours. 2) Clone to have stagging environment. 3) Test your changes in stagging environment. 4) If step 3 success, apply to production database.

But does flyway validate schema table against entity? yes or no? if yes how it does it?

Flyway validate will check the checksum of the migration it has available with the checksum recorded in the Schema History Table. It does not check that the schema in the database matches what it should.
I work for Redgate - and we have a command to check for drift at the Enterprise tier https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/check-drift-237928884.html
